# Type deduction with template, method pointer and strings

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction, template-argument-deduction

I have encounter serious template type deduction problem when I use method pointer in argument of a template function.

Let's take the following code:

```
template <class ClassT, typename Arg1T>
inline void testTemplateFct(ClassT * clazz,
                void (ClassT::*fctPtr)(Arg1T),
                const Arg1T & arg1)
{

}


class TestClass
{

public:
  void testMethodIntArg(int arg)
  {}

  void testMethodDoubleArg(double arg)
  {}

  void testMethodStringArg(const char * arg);

};



int main()
{
  TestClass testClass;

  testTemplateFct(&testClass,
          &TestClass::testMethodIntArg,
          10);

  testTemplateFct(&testClass,
          &TestClass::testMethodDoubleArg,
          10.0);

  /// BEGINNING OF MY PROBLEM
  testTemplateFct(&testClass,
          &TestClass::testMethodStringArg,
          "a string...");
  /// END OF MY PROBLEM

  return 0;
}
```

If I compile it using g++, I get the following error message:

```
$ g++ ArgumentDeduction.cpp -o ArgumentDeduction
ArgumentDeduction.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
ArgumentDeduction.cpp:42:18: error: no matching function for call to ‘testTemplateFct(TestClass*, void (TestClass::*)(const char*), const char [12])’
     "a string...");
                  ^
ArgumentDeduction.cpp:4:13: note: candidate: template<class ClassT, class Arg1T> void testTemplateFct(ClassT*, void (ClassT::*)(Arg1T), const Arg1T&)
 inline void testTemplateFct(ClassT * clazz,
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ArgumentDeduction.cpp:4:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
ArgumentDeduction.cpp:42:18: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘const Arg1T’ (‘const char*’ and ‘char [12]’)
     "a string...");
```

If I remove the reference of the third argument of method `testTemplateFct` the problem disappears (HOWEVER I ABSOLUTELY NEED THE REFERENCE IN ORDER TO AVOID COPY)

```
template <class ClassT, typename Arg1T>
inline void testTemplateFct(ClassT * clazz,
                void (ClassT::*fctPtr)(Arg1T),
                const Arg1T  arg1)
{}
```

I understand more or less the error message but I do not understand why there is an ambiguity between `const char*` and `char [12]`. I do not understand why the problem disappears when I remove the reference.

Finally, I would strongly appreciate any help in order to correct this code while keeping the reference

> PS: I know that I can "force" the type deduction by doing:
>
> ```
> testTemplateFct(&testClass,
>                 &TestClass::testMethodStringArg,
>                 (const char *) "a string...");
> ```
>
> but I don't like it very much

Comment: How much would you dislike `testTemplateFct(&testClass, &TestClass::testMethodStringArg, +"a string...");`?

Comment: Better. However, it bypasses my problem but it does not solve it

Answer (score 2):

> I do not understand why there is an ambiguity between `const char*` and `char [12]`.

Note that `"a string..."` is an array with type `const char[12]`. For the function template `testTemplateFct`, the parameter `arg1` is declared as a *reference*, i.e. `const Arg1T &`, then array-to-pointer decay won't occur in [template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) and `Arg1T` is deduced as `char[12]`, which doesn't match the deduced type of `Arg1T` from the 2nd argument, i.e. `const char*`, so deduction failed.

> I do not understand why the problem disappears when I remove the reference.

When the parameter is declared as pass-by-value array-to-pointer decay is applied; then both the deduced type of `Arg1T` from the 2nd and 3rd argument will be `const char*` and everything work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your template requires that both the occurrences of `Arg1T` are deduced to the same type. I believe that is not what you want. Instead the types should be deduced independently:

```
template <class ClassT, typename Arg1T, typename GivenT>
inline void testTemplateFct(ClassT * clazz,
                void (ClassT::*fctPtr)(Arg1T),
                GivenT &&arg1)
{
    //example use
    (clazz->*fctPtr)(std::forward<GivenT>(arg1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two basic options.

The first one is to change your invocation to:

```
testTemplateFct(&testClass,
          &TestClass::testMethodStringArg,
          (const char *)"a string...");
```

The second option is to add an overload:

```
template <class ClassT, size_t n>
inline void testTemplateFct(ClassT * clazz,
                void (ClassT::*fctPtr)(const char *),
                const char (&arg1)[n])
{
    testTemplateFct<ClassT, const char *>(clazz, fctPtr, arg1);
}
```

Pick which one works best for you.

A literal character string is actually a `const char[n]`, and not a `const char *`. [The `const char` array decays to a `const char *`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying) in an ordinary function call; but this decay does not occur as part of template deduction; hence the problem.